# Can't Call My Method: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a text boxes which allows users to input their Date of birth. I also created a data base linked to this text box as part of my registration page. I created class called Members which contains two methods one of which has parameters.
My problem is I can n't convert Text Box in Date time in my Web User Control!

This is the two methods in the Class `Members.cs`

```
public string Register()
{
    if (Add())
        return "User Added successfully";
    else
        return "User not added, please change username and try again!";
}

public string Register(string username, string password, string name, string phone, string gender, System.DateTime dateofbirth, string email, string company, string question, string answer)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.company = company;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
    return Register();
}
```

Code in my Web User Control :

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Members M = new Members();
    lblMsg.Text = M.Register(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtName.Text,txtEmail.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtCo.Text, rbnGender.SelectedValue, Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text), txtQuestion.Text, txtAnswer.Text);         
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: Try entering 01/01/81 as date of birth. If it goes well then you need to specify the date time format as dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy, depending on your system

Comment: I have these errors:  Error3Argument 6: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime' 
Error 4 Argument 8: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string' 
Error 1 No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments 
Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'Members.Register(string, string, string, string, string, System.DateTime, string, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method takes these parameters:

```
username, password, name, phone, gender, dateofbirth, email, company, question, answer
```

But you are passing in these, in the wrong order:

```
txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtCo.Text, rbnGender.SelectedValue, Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text), txtQuestion.Text, txtAnswer.Text
```

It should be:

```
lblMsg.Text = M.Register(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtName.Text, txtPhone.Text, rbnGender.SelectedValue, Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text), txtEmail.Text, txtCo.Text, txtQuestion.Text, txtAnswer.Text);
```

However, you should probably use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert your date of birth field.